# Timer schedule vs scheduleAtFixedRate?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0; 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Run Me ~" + ++i);
        System.out.println("Test");

    }

}

Case 1 :-
    TimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 1000,6000); // line 1
    System.out.println("End"); // here is bebug point.
```

My Expectation of `schedule()` method (as per my understanding given in `javadocs` where each execution is scheduled once previous task execution is completed) 
that two threads should be
created after line 1.

One for `timer` which spawns another thread for tasks. Once first task thread dies
another will be created and son on. But at debug point , i just see one thread corresponding to `Timer`. Why
not thread for tasks which implement `Runnable`?

```
Case 2 :-

    TimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000,6000); // line 1
    System.out.println("End"); // here is bebug point.
```

My Expectation of `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method(as per my understanding given in javadocs where  each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled 
execution time of the initial execution) that around 17 threads(dont pay much attention
to 17. It can be more or less to that. But it should be greater than 2 ) should be
created after line 1.

One for `timer`  which should spawn  16 other thread corresponding two each task. At first task sleeps
for 100 second, `Timer` should create another thread corresponding to next task and similarly for other task.
But at debug point , i just see one thread corresponding to `Timer`. Here also i can see sequential execution of task.  Why not 17 threads?

**UPDATE** :- As per [ScheduleAtFixedRate javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) , `each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up. what does that mean?` To me it gives impression, if second task is due even first task is not completed, then timer will create new thread for due task. Is n't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc for `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) says

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that
>   is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially.

Basically it holds a queue of tasks to which it adds when you schedule them. It uses one thread to iterate over the queue and execute the tasks.

Comment: but then whats is the difference scheduleAtFixedRate and schedule? As per my example are they supposed to behave similar?

Comment: @MSach It's in the javadoc. `schedule` is fixed-delay while `scheduleatFixedRate` is fixed-rate. This has an impact on when the scheduled task will run.

Comment: As per ScheduleAtFixedRate javadocs,  each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up. what does that mean? To me it gives impression, if  second task is due even first task is not completed, then timer will create new thread for due task. Is n't it?

Comment: @MSach No, there is no other thread other than the `Timer` thread. The tasks are in the queue. If there's a delay, it will just wait less time in between executions.

Comment: @MSach That is, in the case of fixed rate. In the case of fixed delay, the next execution will happen after the delay.

Answer (score 5):

`Timer` uses the [Active Object](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf) pattern under the hood, so there is only ever a single thread being used and scheduling a new task on the timer adds that task to the thread's tasks queue.

The timer thread keeps track of all the tasks in it's queue and sleeps until the next task is scheduled. Then, it wakes up and executes the task itself by invoking `task.run()` directly, meaning that it does not spawn another thread to execute the code.

This also means that if you schedule two tasks to execute at the same time then, true to the Active Object pattern, they will be executed sequentially (one after another) on the same thread of control. This means the second task will execute after it's scheduled time (but probably not by much).

Now, to unequivocally answer your question, here is the scheduling logic from `Timer.class` that schedules the next time that the task should be run again (from lines 262-272 [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Timer.java)):

```
// set when the next task should be launched
if (task.fixedRate) {
    // task is scheduled at fixed rate
    task.when = task.when + task.period;
} else {
    // task is scheduled at fixed delay
    task.when = System.currentTimeMillis()
            + task.period;
}

// insert this task into queue
insertTask(task);
```

`task.fixedRate` is set to true if you use one of the `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` methods and is set to false if you use one of the `timer.schedule()` methods.

`task.when` is the "time" (ticks) that the task was scheduled to run.

`task.period` is the interval you passed to the `timer.schedule*()` method.

So, from the code we can see that if you use a fixed rate then a repeating task will be scheduled to run relative to when it was first started. If you don't use a fixed rate, then it is scheduled to run relative to when it was last run (which will drift relative to a fixed rate, unless your task is never delayed and takes less than one tick to execute).

This also means that if a task falls behind and it is on a fixed rate, then `Timer` will keep rescheduling the task for immediate execution until it catches up to the total number of times it should have ran over a given period.

So if you have a task, say a `ping()` that you schedule to run at a fixed rate every 10ms and there is temporary blocking in the `ping()` method to where it takes 20ms to execute, then the `Timer` will call `ping()` again immediately after the previous call finished, and it will keep doing so until the given rate is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The timer class creates one thread per instance of the timer class and this thread do all tasks scheduled Timer#schedule or Timer#scheduleAtFixRate.

So, as you ovserved, the timer creates only one thread.

A task would have came start time before the preciding task has finished, then the follwing task has waited until the preciding task has finished.

So, Timer "never" create another thread although the preciding task hasn't finished and the time the following task has to start has come.

So, I advise you that:
if you want to schedule tasks and do the tasks on time whether a preciding task has finished or not, use  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor instead of Timer.

And though if you do not want, it's prefer to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor than Timer because for one thing, tasks scheduled by Timer would never have done if a task would have threw RuntimeException or Error.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule will not execute the missed task if the start time is in the past.
scheduleAtFixedRate will execute the missed tasks if the start time is in the past.For the missed tasks, the start time will be calculated based last task's end time. When missed tasks are executed fully, the new normal tasks' start time will be calculated based on last task's start time.

BR Sanchez